# Autenticação para múltiplos usuários com ASP.NET MVC e .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde há a necessidade de dois tipos de usuários, o cliente, que irá acessar somente o *frontend*, e o administrador, associado ao *backoffice*. Preciso que estes usuários sejam autenticados em "cookies" diferentes, já que fazem parte de áreas distintas.

Estive vendo sobre `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`, mas parece que não há possibilidade atribuir uma identificação diferente para o cookie de autenticação desta função.

Poderiam me dar uma ideia de por onde começar?

Obs: Procuro um método que eu possa manter as sessões separadas, sem a necessidade de utilização de *Roles* para manter o acesso ao painel frontend e backoffice associado ao seu tipo de usuário. Porque possuo dois formulários de autenticação (um para o cliente e outro para o administrador) e separar por *Roles* seria um "obstáculo", além disso, provavelmente será comum um administrador possuir também uma conta de usuário e vice-versa, e querer autenticar em ambos ao mesmo tempo. Portanto manter as autenticações separadas fornecerá mais flexibilidade nestes casos.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem qual seria esse "obstáculo" de usar Roles. Se um administrador pode utilizar a função cliente basta liberar o acesso. Não precisa de autenticar 2x o mesmo usuário para isso.

Comment: Não posso, porque o acesso do cliente depende de outros dados que só são preenchidos através do cadastro, enquanto que para o administrador é totalmente diferente. E também trabalho com duas tabelas diferentes, uma para clientes e outra para administradores.

Comment: Outro motivo é que já trabalho com Roles para o backoffice (Super Administradores, Gerentes e Editor), então controlar mais uma Role para impedir o cliente de acessar o painel complicaria a estrutura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar nomes de *cookies* diferentes para logins diferentes. Dessa forma, um cookie não vai sobrescrever o outro.

Você pode setar o valor do *cookie* no arquivo Web.config, mudando o valor do atributo "name":

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
 <forms name=".NomeDoCookie" domain="seudominio.com" ... />
</authentication>
```

Mas para ter dois nomes diferentes, você precisaria fazer a autenticação de forma manual, utilizando valores diferentes para o atributo *cookiePath*:

```
FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, false, "cookiePath");
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false, "cookiePath");
```

Dessa forma, cada tipo de usuário seria autenticado de uma forma independente.

Espero ter ajudado.